# Pandas date range with freq every 6 months anchored to Jan/ June

Tags: python, pandas, time

I'm trying to get all the dates "YYYY-01-01" and "YYYY-06-01" between two times using pandas `date_range`.

I thought I might be able to do this using:

```
pd.date_range("2023-01-05", "2024-12-01", freq="6MS-JAN")
```

But it looks like you can't use anchors in this way. Is there another easy way I can do this using the freq argument?

Given the start and end times in my example above, I want the dates "2023-06-01", "2024-01-01" and "2024-06-01".

Of course I could get the dates I want with a for-loop, but I'd like to know whether it can be achieved more easily.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `freq` in your scenario only with an anchorable frequency.

For instance if you wanted to have all quarters, you could use:

```
pd.date_range('2023-01-05', '2024-12-01', freq='QS-DEC')
# DatetimeIndex(['2023-03-01', '2023-06-01', '2023-09-01', '2023-12-01', '2024-03-01', '2024-06-01', '2024-09-01', '2024-12-01'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='QS-DEC')
```

Which is pretty close to what you want.

Unfortunately:

```
pd.date_range('2023-01-05', '2024-12-01', freq='2QS-DEC')
# DatetimeIndex(['2023-03-01', '2023-09-01', '2024-03-01', '2024-09-01'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='2QS-DEC')
```

Would start on the next available quarter, which here would be `'2023-03-01'`:

Unfortunately, again, there is no anchorable semester frequency in pandas.

A workaround might be to get all quarters, then filter the 2 and 4:

```
out = pd.date_range('2023-01-05', '2024-12-01', inclusive='left', freq='QS-DEC')
out = out[out.quarter%2 == 0]
```

Output:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2023-06-01', '2023-12-01', '2024-06-01'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Or with `MS` (which should be less efficient since we have to discard more unwanted months):

```
out = pd.date_range('2023-01-05', '2024-12-01', inclusive='left', freq='MS')
out = out[out.month.isin([1, 6])]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
dates = pd.date_range("2023-05-01", "2024-01-01", freq='MS')
months = dates.month # Store all months
dates = dates[(months == 6) | (months == 1)] # Filter dates
dates
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get a date range with a frequency of 6 months starting in January or June, you can still achieve this with `pd.date_range`, but instead of trying to use a custom anchor with the `freq` argument, you'll adjust the start date manually if needed and use a 6-month frequency (`'6M'`). Then, filter out to keep only January and June dates.

However, when you use `'6M'` with `pd.date_range`, it generally won't align exactly with the start of the month, so a more reliable approach uses '6MS' as the frequency but in conjunction with a slight adjustment if the initial date is not aligned as desired.

Here's a method to do so:

```py
import pandas as pd

def generate_custom_range(start, end):
   # Adjust start date to the next occurrence of January or June
   if 1 <= start.month < 6 and start.day > 1:
      start = pd.Timestamp(year=start.year, month=6, day=1)
   elif start.month >= 6 and start.day > 1:
      start = pd.Timestamp(year=start.year  + 1, month=1, day=1)
   # Generate the date range
   dates = pd.date_range(start, end, freq='6MS')
   return dates
```

Example usage:

```
start_date = "2023-01-05"
end_date = "2024-12-01"

start = pd.to_datetime(start_date)
end = pd.to_datetime(end_date)

dates = generate_custom_range(start, end)
print(dates)
```

Example result:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2023-06-01', '2023-12-01', '2024-06-01', '2024-12-01'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='6MS')
```